# How to get main site url inside webpart?

Tags: sharepoint, wss, wss-3.0

I need to get main site url from inside my custom webpart. Is there any programming way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try :

```
        SPWeb currentWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;
        SPWeb rootWeb = currentWeb.Site.RootWeb;
```